# Remove rows with duplicate string values in one column, and append strings from another columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am looking to remove duplicate rows based on the values in a column ("Name"), but append the corresponding string values in another column("Occupation").

Duplicate entry is "Jack"

I have a dataframe:

| Name | center | Occupation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | Miami | Clerk |
| Alice | Tx | Manager |
| Jack | San Jose | PO |
| Cathy | Houston | Security |

And i am expecting this

| Name | center | Occupation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | Miami | Clerk PO |
| Alice | Tx | Manager |
| Cathy | Houston | Security |

Appreciate any answer on this

Comment: so for "Occupation" you would want to join the values, what about for "center"? Do you just want to keep the first match per name? Or if not, what type of aggregation you'd want there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for something along the lines of:

```
df.groupby('Name',as_index=False).agg(
    {'center':'first','Occupation':lambda x: ' '.join(x)}
    )
```

which get's you:

```
    Name   center Occupation
0  Alice       Tx    Manager
1  Cathy  Houston   Security
2   Jack    Miami   Clerk PO
```

However, I can't be sure what type of aggregation you'd want for 'center' - using `first` now which get's your desired outcome.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i would like to keep the same order in the column 'Name' --Jack, Alice, cathy

Comment: Please then include ```df.groupby('Name',sort=False)``` in the ```groupby``` clause

Answer (score 0):

You can do a groupby, and then aggregate the columns as you like. For occupation you already wrote to join, for center I chose `first`.

```
out = df.groupby('Name', as_index=False, sort=False).agg({'center': 'first', 'Occupation': ' '.join})
print(out)
```

Output:

```
    Name   center Occupation
0   Jack    Miami   Clerk PO
1  Alice       Tx    Manager
2  Cathy  Houston   Security
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i would like to keep the same order in the column 'Name' --Jack, Alice, cathy